# Bars on side of navigation bar when hovering over

Tags: css, xhtml, html

I don't know how to get rid of the bars on the side when I hover over the navbar. Can anyone help? I dont want to change the look or position of the navigation bar. I only want to make the parts that are not affected by hovering affected by it.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Simple Site</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
<div id="body">
<center>
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="biography.html">Biography</a></li>
    </ul>
    </center>
</div>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    @charset "utf-8";


#container {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:960px;
    background-color:#666666;
}

#body {
    background-color:#666666;
    width:960px;
    height:500px;
    border:2px solid #FFFFFF;
    margin-top:50px auto;
}

.navbar {margin:0px;
    background-color:#66FF33;
    text-align:center;
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom:none;
    padding-left:0px    
}

ul.navbar li {
    width:19%;
    display:inline-block;
}

ul.navbar a {

    display:block;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px 0px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

ul.navbar a:hover {
    background-color:#33FFD7;
}

body {
    background-color:#333333;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing all the space between your `<li>` elements.  The spaces are creating extra, well, space between links.  This adds to the 100% width 5 elements at 20% width should be creating.

```
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li><li><a href="about.html">About</a></li><li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li><li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li><li><a href="biography.html">Biography</a></li>
```

I hope that there is a more satisfying answer than this, but if you just want the quick and easy, this will work.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vNJ3x/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: can you give me a example ?

Comment: Added a jsfiddle.  I did make an edit to your css.  I changed the 19% to 20% for `li`.